# When first loading local .net pages very slow (through IIS, about 6~7 minutes) after build project in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2012

Use IIS to configure the local site, and then compile the project is completed, the browser loads the page becomes very slow, before although it will be slower, but up to 1 to 2 minutes to load out (may contain some precompiled loading dll file), but now become very slow, for the first time takes 6 to 7 minutes to load.

I used the 'Fusion Log Viewer' to view the assembly binding log loading, found some dlls take a long time.

Note that the image below shows the page loading assembly:
[assembly loding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iMyk.png)

I made reference to this link:

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx

Then I have set the file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config \web.config"
Configuration node:

```
 <Compilation batch = "false" optimizeCompilations = "true">
```

But the effect is not obvious, while visiting some contains some user controls the time is still very slow.

Here I chose a relatively slow dll loading a log, I hope someone knows because of what is so slow, to help analyze.

```
Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/7/2016 @ 8:02:27 PM) 

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr =0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = QUOTIT\webuser
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f\bb9a0eb4\App_Web_mev5nz2h.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/Sprints/Sprint/src/Quotit2010.root/Quotit/Webs/Ipro/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\Sprints\Sprint\src\Quotit2010.root\Quotit\Webs\Ipro\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f
LOG: AppName = bb9a0eb4
Calling assembly : (Unknown).

===

LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Sprints\Sprint\src\Quotit2010.root\Quotit\Webs\Ipro\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/quotit_apps_ipro/4dcf303f/bb9a0eb4/App_Web_mev5nz2h.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f\bb9a0eb4\App_Web_mev5nz2h.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: App_Web_mev5nz2h, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Re-apply policy for where-ref bind.
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase matches what is found in default context. Keep the result in default context.
LOG: The post-policy assembly reference requires probing again.
LOG: Switch from LoadFrom context to default context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\Sprints\Sprint\src\Quotit2010.root\Quotit\Webs\Ipro\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/quotit_apps_ipro/4dcf303f/bb9a0eb4/App_Web_mev5nz2h.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f\bb9a0eb4\App_Web_mev5nz2h.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\quotit_apps_ipro\4dcf303f\bb9a0eb4\App_Web_mev5nz2h.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

In fact, I have been wondering why the problem occurs, and I have never turn over about IIS configuration

Comment: 1. Don't use debug build. 2. Precompile the web app. 3. Make sure you use a powerful enough machine. The very first access triggers the ASP.NET runtime initialization which is always slow, so you can only optimize it to an acceptable level but could not eliminate it.

Comment: The strange thing is probably in May before the first load in 1-2 minutes, this is acceptable, but in May installed mvc 5.0, what impact will this do?

Comment: then use a profiler to check deeper. Fusion log does not show a full image and you can easily miss the most important things.

Comment: OK, thanks, would u please provider a link to get the profiler tool?

Comment: ask Google please.